# Android Studio stuck at "Analyzing..."

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

In my Android project (Android 4.2 Canary 15), completion does not work anymore, and neither does syntax highlighting. This is happening in one Android project only (the others work well).

[image: No completion, no syntax highlighting, ...]

I have tried to clean, rebuild the project, create a new project and import files, but no changes... I have tried to delete .idea directory and all .iml files, but not better...

In the "File" menu, I've just tried the option "Invalidate caches / restart" and now all classes in my project are blocked at the state "Analyzing..." and completion still does not work...

[image: Analyzing...]

Build and run project work, and my application starts well on my phone, but all intellij features
are inactive.

Comment: seems i can fix it by deleting c:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Google/AndroidStudio4.2 (win10). Usually it is safe to remove.

Comment: I found a less nuclear approach was to just delete `c:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Google/AndroidStudioPreview2021.1/caches`

Comment: Oh, you saved me @ChrisHorner. Thank you.

Comment: Chris Horner´s suggestion works perfectly for AS 2020.3 Artic Fox

Answer (score 57):

It appears that the Kotlin plugin was, indeed, the culprit.

Today (24 May 2021), a new version was released `1.5.10`, and as soon as I installed it, everything went back to normal.

**Synopsis**: After upgrading from version `1.4.32` of Kotlin plugin to `1.5.0`, code inspection, completion, linking to sources, javadocs, etc. all stop working (stuck at "Analyzing..." as the images [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw1qU.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zdio.jpg) show), and only return for a few seconds/minutes when sth triggers a new analysis (eg. a gradle build, commit, loading new files, etc).

History of the plugin updates for reference can be found [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin/versions/stable)

Comment: works for me, but you can't use Jetpack Compose with 1.5.10 . Any other solution?

Comment: Got to the same problem today, reinstalled kotlin and some other plugins are disabled for me, reenabled and now working good.

Comment: I had the same problem. Just updating the plugin did not fix it, I had to update the kotlin version from 1.4.10 to 1.5.10

Comment: @CarsonHolzheimer nobody should update the plugin w/o the language version :) they should share the same version variable

Comment: @Ace No, the plugin should be backwards compatible. A language increase is a big change that isn't intended to be tied to the particular ide/plugin

Comment: Works! I had to update Gradle Plugin to 6.1.1 as well and everything was fine!

Comment: I just had it on ArcticFox 2020.3.1 Patch2, with Kotlin 1.4.20 (Kotlin plugin updated to latest, like 1.5.20 or smth). Nothing helped, until I changed Kotlin version in project to 1.5.20, synced (problem got solved). Then I was able to change it back to 1.4.20 without loosing working editor.

Answer (score 27):

Try it:

> **File** --> **settings** --> **Plugins** --> **Android ButterKnife Zelezny** --> **disenable**

Comment: Ooooops that's it !!! what is the problem??

Comment: Saved my day. Thanks  Just an update.
File --> settings --> Plugins --> Android ButterKnife Zelezny --> Uninstall (Restart AndroidStudio)

Comment: just saved my life!!!!

Comment: Fantastic!  you saved my time a lot

Answer (score 25):

**Android Studio** -> **File** -> **Invalidate Caches and Restart**

Nothing else helped me.

Answer (score 24):

you can just change the Kotlin version to something else and then gradle sync again
This will solve the issue

you will find it in build.gradle file(project)

```
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.10"  //I used this
```

you can also roll back to your previous version. If you want this should not recreate the issue.

Comment: I don’t think 'change the Kotlin version to something else' should be one of the solutions. We can't just get up and change kotlin version in projects just for sake of getting rid of the error

Comment: I think it's similar to reinstall

Answer (score 7):

From my project I deleted the files

```
.idea/gradle.xml
.idea/workspace.xml
```

and it solved it for me.

Seems to be that I had previously configured the project's gradle incorrectly and even after several reinstalls I wasn't getting any luck.

Comment: I tried and deleted both files but still, I am facing the same issue.

Comment: It's worked for me + update kotlin plugin to 1.5.10

Comment: It's worked, just deleted both files and invalidated caches/ Restart

Answer (score 6):

I just update the Koltin version to 1.5.20 and it works!!

Comment: The answer here which you are saying thanks for is https://stackoverflow.com/a/67673387/7733418 Isn't it?

Answer (score 5):

Kotlin version 1.4.10 magically stopped working in the IDE.

The problems are not related to the IDE version but rather to the integration of the kotlin plugin and the IDE.

```
kotlinVersion = '1.5.10'

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
```

Then Sync Project and Compile.

Finally you can see that the problem of **Analyzing** disappears and the IDE becomes intelligent again.

---

It is possible that after updating kotlin you have minimal errors in other libraries so you also have to update or fix them (I happened with Room)

GL

Answer (score 5):

This is a looming AS IDE issue correlated with the Kotlin plugin, Have tried literally every answer here with tooth and nail, but nothing worked. There were chains of errors. Finally, removing the AS cache folder manually worked for me -

`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\caches`

```
Artic fox sucks!
```

You may also try to update the Kotlin plugin to the latest if possible and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: In windows 11 deleting cache  fails  due  to administrator  permissions , deleting the whole AndroidStudio2020.3 worked for  me

Comment: @AustineGwa Similar thing worked for me

Answer (score 4):

The one solution that worked for me (working in Canary 2021.1.1) was to completely uninstall the Kotlin plugin from Android Studio, restart, let Android Studio install it automatically, and then everything worked again.

The root cause of this issue was that Android Studio "accidentally?" updated Kotlin plugin to an M1 version (I'm on x64), namely 211-1.5.30-M1-release-141-AS7442.40, when updating the plugin. I'm not sure why, but from now a check of what is going to be updated in Canary seems mandatory to avoid these kind of stuff to happen.

Comment: I had tried all the other solutions, none of them worked, after following this tip, everything worked again, now the analyzer is working again

Answer (score 3):

this issue comes from plugins

1- update plugins

2- step by step disable plugins to find incorrect plugin

3- as advance people please report issue to providers for solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

in `Arctic Fox version (2020.3.1)` I fixed it by updating `Gradle` Plugin version `7.0.0`.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is 100% working for the above issue

```
  ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.21"

 classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just update the dependency "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2" to "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0". And it's gone, working normally

Answer (score 0):

After many hours, I finally uninstalled Android Studio, delete all Android directory, clean registry and reinstall Android Studio stable version.

Comment: that's hardly an answer/solution to your question/problem. You should've put this in a comment below your question, at most. Anyway, still waiting for an actual fix.

Comment: I did this and yet its stuck. So I am guessing it's something to do with the Kotlin Plugin itself. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the plugin, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

disable Compose plugin.  the only way work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using

- Jetpack Compose 1.0.5 (haven't tested with 1.0.0-1.0.4 but they should work too)
- Java 11
- Kotlin 1.5.31 (tested 1.5.10 working too)

the other answers don't work

What works is the following in your project build.gradle:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
            useIR = true
            freeCompilerArgs += [
                    "-Xallow-jvm-ir-dependencies",
                    "-P",
                    "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck=true"
            ]
        }
    }
```

(compose compiler was blocking Kotlin compiler from completing jobs)

and **Invalidate Caches & Restart**

Answer (score 0):

for me file analysis is only getting stuck in kotlin files with co-routines. upgrading co-routines version to the latest helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes some files are stucking to me at analazying, I resolve that issue by:

1. Just copy / paste that file with the different name
2. Then remove the original file and rename the copied file with the original name.