# Why are my files still being 'Analyzed' in Android studio, intellisense and autosuggest doesnt seem to work

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-4.1, android-studio-4.2

For this particular project, Android studio just shows analyzing files, doesn't show any errors and the IntelliSense is also not auto-suggesting. I have tried to invalidate cache/ restart, checked that android studio is not in power mode, and also deleted the project locally and cloned it again, what can be the issue?

It was working fine till 2 days ago but today when I opened the app and tried to build it and make some changes to a few files, it just wont work.
I am on Android Studio 4.2.1 on macOS Big Sur 11.2.1

If I create a new project the studio is working fine but just for this project its not working

Here are the screenshots

[image]

[image]

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have posted the same answer in another post, you can take the reference from the below link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67984260/11414681

You just need to Upgrade the latest kotlin version.

1. Upgrade the dependency in the project's build.gradle file.

   ```
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10"
   ```
2. Upgrade the dependency in the app's build.gradle file.

   ```
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.10"
   ```

Comment: Yup I kinda figured it out after a couple of days and did that, it worked, thankyou so much for the comment though!!!

Comment: Updating the kotlin version to 1.5.10 helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Delete .idea , .gradle andr buid folder from your project path.
After delete your project from Android Studio and re-open and its work.
Sometimes android studio has been not working properly so ignore this bugs its nothing.

Comment: Yes this would work too, however in my case simply upgrading my kotlin version seemed to work! Thankyou for your answer though!!

Answer (score 0):

Just make **File -> Invalidate caches and restart**

Check my answer here, [stackoverflow.com/a/68755611/2281717](http://stackoverflow.com/a/68755611/2281717)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just update all dependencies on my Android App Project. And it's working