# Android Studio stuck at "Analyzing" even after changing Kotlin version

Tags: android, android-studio

I am currently using the `1.4.32` version of Kotlin. But any time I write something, the studio is stuck at "Analyzing".
Even if I write some error code, it won't show anything.
[image]

I have tried updating the version of Kotlin, [as told here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64984549/android-studio-stuck-at-analyzing).

But that didn't worked as well. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Upgrade to 1.5.20

Comment: Tried that, didn't worked

Comment: What's your gradle plugin version? Recently upgrading to 1.5.31 gave me the same error

Comment: The plugin version is `7.0.2`

Comment: Have you tried invalidating cache & restart? Clear android studio in %appdata%

Comment: A huge thanks. The second method worked! I don't know how, but clearing Android Studio from %appdata% worked

Comment: It's an issue with gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear android studio in %appdata%

Is an issue with Gradle version upgrades sometimes.

Checkout other questions with answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68804289/7741377

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68586517/7741377

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30051160)

Comment: Done that, updated with related info.